# How does the Smooth Talker skill work when other players are involved?

Tags: payday-2

**Note: As of update 25, this question is no longer relevant for the PC version since the Smooth Talker skill has been removed.**

Players can normally answer two pagers successfully without any help from skills ([Source](http://payday.wikia.com/wiki/Enemies_(Payday_2)#Guard)), but that number increases to four for players with the [Smooth Talker Skill](http://payday.wikia.com/wiki/Skills#Smooth_Talker). **How does this work when some players have the skill but others don't?**

Can anyone successfully answer the first three pages as long as the "skilled" player answers the fourth? Does the "skilled" player have to answer all four for this to work?

Also, how do banks find enough pagers in this day and age for every guard to have one? Actually, never mind, [I think I know the answer to that one](http://cdn.uproxx.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/dennis-duffy-phone.gif).

**I've heard varying reports on how many pagers can be answered without the Smooth Talker Skill. Some sources say two and others say three.*

Comment: Another thing to consider; can a smooth talker answer the first pager and a normal player the next 3?

Comment: Note that Smooth Talker no longer exists in the game and was replaced by Spotter.

Comment: @3ventic Good call, I updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Not on Xbox or PS3. All still in it's beginnings. No DLC or updates.

Comment: @Brok3n Good call, I updated my note to indicate that I'm referring to the PC version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The detail on the [Payday 2 skills site](http://www.pd2skills.info/), which utilises information scraped from the game files suggests the following:

- With no skills, any player should be able to answer two pagers without issue
- With **Smooth Talker**, a player with the skill can answer four pagers without issue

If you have a team with a player that has the Smooth Talker ability, the rest of the team is able to answer the first two pagers but the player with Smooth Talker has to answer the rest.

If you have a team with multiple Smooth Talkers, this will still only guarantee that you can answer four pagers, but it gives you more flexibility regarding who in your team can answer.

Answer (score 4):

The first two pagers can be answered by anyone, the third and fourth **must** be answered by the player with the smooth talker skill.  A fifth pager will always sound the alarm, and if a non-smooth talker player answers the third or fourth.  When you include the dominator skill, that is a total of 5 guards that can be removed from the equation.

[source](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=172362030)

Comment: What happens if 2 people have smooth talker? Can they each do 2 extra?

Comment: @user55133 - In 2013 it was 4 in total.  The answer even talks about this.  The skill has actually changed since Sept 2013 well documented in the changelogs.